# How to create Dataset in Einstein Analytics Salesforce/Pardot

Tags: einstein-analytics, pardot, data-set

I have implemented B2B marketing Analytics in Salesforce Training Version i.e. it is synced with Pardot data now. My question is that do we need to create a dataset or does it automatically takes data from pardot and automatically creates datasets in the analytics studio app? Also if the dataset is needed to be created then how do I create that dataset in analytics studio app.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome you have implemented B2BMA in Salesforce. So here are some key points of B2BMA in Salesforce and Pardot:-

1. Some of the data set are predefined configure in your analytics studio. It will fetch your pardot data in your analytics studio and if you want to create your own dataset then navigate to the Analytics studio and you can create your own dataset and select what field you want to select to see your data.

   2. Thill will help you to show your pardot data in a pictorial way. Earlier it was not possible in pardot.

Here what i did :-

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6433411125022429184

Let me know if you need more help.